# Is there a way to terminate the bot conversation and allow an admin to continue?

Tags: botframework

Currently, on the Facebook bot, if an admin on the page responds why the Page's messaging tab and the user responds, the bot still gets the message and tries to use it.

Is there a way to terminate the bot conversation and allow an admin user to continue?

Comment: You would have to do that in your backend code